# why is this sed command not working?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to strip some part of parent directories from result of pwd command. For a first step, I wanted to get the string part after 'home' with sed but I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think I've properly set the substring to be made and to be the output of sed substitute.

```
$ pwd
/home/user1/projects/bashscript
$ pwd | sed -r 's/\*home(\*)/\1/'
/home/user1/projects/bashscript
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct regex for sed is:

```
pwd | sed -r 's/.*home(.*)/\1/'
```

`*` can match anything in shell i.e. **glob pattern** but in regex equivalent pattern is `.*`.

However if you're using `bash` there is no need to use `sed`. You can do it using **bash string manipulation**:

```
echo "${PWD/\/home/}"
```

---

**Update:** Based on Ed's comment below if there are multiple `/home` in `PWD`.

Assuming `PWD=/foo/123/home/dir/home/abcd`:

it is more correct to use:

```
echo "${PWD#*/home}"
/dir/home/abcd
```

- `#` will find a glob pattern from left (start) of the string
- `*/home` will remove everything until **first occurrence** of `/home` in value of `PWD` from left

Comment: how come '.' makes all the difference? Doesn't a single dot just mean some character? the * can mean a whole lot more and longer so why doesn't a single * suffice?

Comment: @kwagjj: `*` can match anything in shell i.e. glob pattern but in regex correct pattern is `.*`

Comment: glob pattern.. i'll look into that. oh an thanks for the bash suggestions. I think this is what I needed

Comment: It'll fail if a user's login name or any other part of the path contains the string `home`. This just isn't the right way to approach this problem - better to count the `/`s or do something different depending on what the final goal is but the OP would need to tell us more about his problem and give better examples to know the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have update answer with another option.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.*` (*matches any character zero or more times*) instead of `\*` . `*` is a special character in regex which repeats the previous token zero or more times. Dot in regex matches any character except line breaks.

```
$ pwd | sed -r 's~.*/home/(.*)~\1~'
```

OR

```
$ pwd | sed -r 's~.*/home(/.*)~\1~'
```

Use a different regex delimiter other than forward slash because your input contains forward slashes. Sometimes it may cause a mesh.